# Adding Button Programmatically Does not Adhere to Text Color

Tags: android, xml, button, themes

I have a button style as below:

```
<style name="ButtonAppTheme" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.Button">
      <!-- ORIGINAL: <item name="android:background">@drawable/apptheme_btn_default_holo_light</item> -->
      <item name="android:background">@drawable/x_button_background</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/x_button_text</item>
      <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/master_fontsize_mid</item>
      <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/button_padleft</item>
      <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/button_padright</item>
      <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
  </style>
```

It is set in the theme as below:

```
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonAppTheme</item>
```

I set this theme in my manifest for my application. However, when I add a button programmatically like this:

```
btn = new Button(activity);
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(R.dimen.button_height, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
btn.setLayoutParams(params);
btn.setText("MyButton");
layout.addView(btn);
```

The background drawable renders fine, but the text is white, not the drawable (grey and red depending on state) that it is supposed to be. How can I ensure my programmatically added buttons are going to adhere fully to this style?

Comment: Try to initialize button this way : btn = new Button(activity,null,R.style.ButtonAppTheme);

Comment: @HareshChhelana If I create the button that way, I don't even get the drawable border.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     style="@style/ButtonAppTheme"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Button" />
```

Programmatically,

```
Button b = new Button(getApplicationContext(), null, R.style.ButtonAppTheme);
```

Comment: android.widget.Button does not have a setStyle method it seems.

Comment: The questions was for adding a button programmatically, not through xml.

Comment: This was suggested by @HareshChhelana above. It did not work. Also, I have tried this with both application and base context.